# Adding multiple buttons and menu buttons on JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way of adding multiple JButtons and Menu Buttons on a JPanel.
I am using the borderLayout and this doesnt seem to work I have already tried to use the flow layout but this seems to stack the buttons in one particular direction.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Menu extends JPanel {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu file;
    private JMenu algorithms;
    private JMenu help;
    private JMenu notes;
    private JMenuItem bubbleSort;
    private JMenuItem insertionSort;
    private JMenuItem selectionSort;
    private JMenuItem mergeSort;
    private JMenuItem quickSort;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    private JButton restartButton;
    private Sorter sorter;
    private JButton pauseButton;
    private JButton startButton;

    public Menu(String algorithmName) {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        file = new JMenu("File");
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        notes = new JMenu("Notes");
        algorithms = new JMenu("Algorithms");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        bubbleSort = new JMenuItem("BubbleSort");
        quickSort = new JMenuItem("QuickSort");
        insertionSort = new JMenuItem("InsertionSort");
        selectionSort = new JMenuItem("SelectionSort");
        mergeSort = new JMenuItem("MergeSort");
        restartButton = new JButton("Restart Algorithm");
        pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
        startButton = new JButton("Start");

        file.add(algorithms);
        file.add(exit);
        algorithms.add(bubbleSort);
        algorithms.add(insertionSort);
        algorithms.add(selectionSort);
        algorithms.add(mergeSort);
        algorithms.add(quickSort);

        menuBar.add(file);
        menuBar.add(notes);
        menuBar.add(help);

        add(restartButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(pauseButton,BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(startButton,BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(menuBar,BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Comment: Why are you adding `JMenuBar` to `JPanel`? I recommend doing some reading on how to create menus: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: And here is some more reading about different layout managers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Answer (score 2):

You can place one component to one direction with `BorderLayout` , seems you need to choose other [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Seems [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) can help you.

Also as recommended don't place `JMenu`/`JMenuBar`/`JMenuItem` to `JPanel`, you need to set a `JMenuBar` to `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Swingdesigner as well. It will give you a WYSIWYG interface, which you can use to study the code.

It's important to know how to do it in code, but the interface will help guide you.